# Como exibir o total de linhas de uma tabela em um label

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, winforms

Não sei como puxar o total de linhas de uma tabela, código:

```
public string Eventos { get; set; }

SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM Active", conn);
SqlDataReader leitor = comando.ExecuteReader();
while (leitor.Read()) {
  //Aqui fica o problema pois não sei como faço para pegar o resultado total das linhas
  Eventos = leitor["Nome"].ToString(); 
  label19.Text = Eventos;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível fazer por SQL, através de um `count`, exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(campo_tabela) AS total FROM tabela
```

A única coisa que vai retornar é o total de registos, mais informações consulte [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).

Para mostrar os valores em um `label` será necessário algo idêntico a isto, exemplo:

```
//string com o comando a ser executado 
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(campo_tabela) AS total FROM tabela"; 

//instância do comando recebendo o comando e a conexão 
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn); 

//abro conexão 
conn.Open(); 

//instância do leitor 
SqlCeDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

//passo os valores para o textbox cliente que será retornado 
txtNome.Text = leitor["total"].ToString();  

//fecha conexão 
conn.Close();
```

Para ver a informação mais detalhada visite [Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Realizar-select-e-exibir-8d90084c).

**EDIT1:**

Tentei corrigir o seu código para o ajudar, penso que basta mudar o valor para `total` na leitura e no query acrescentar `AS total`, o `while` pode ser removido é usado para quando existem mais registos.

Código:

```
public string Eventos { get; set; }

SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) AS total FROM Active", conn);
SqlDataReader leitor = comando.ExecuteReader();

Eventos = leitor["total"].ToString(); 
label19.Text = Eventos;
```

Comment: Como posso exibir na label o total de linhas?

Comment: veja isto tem um exemplo: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Realizar-select-e-exibir-8d90084c

Comment: Editei o post com o novo código

Comment: já editei a resposta deve precisar de algo como o descrito no código

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito simples é usar o método [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.100).aspx) para obter o valor de `Count(*)`

```
var comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM Active", conn);

label19.Text = comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```